# Long-running task performed in foreground is suspended when app goes to background

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

When a user first opens my app, I need to download and install some content from a server before they can begin using the app. The problem is that this takes around 5 minutes on wifi, during which time the app goes into the background and the download is suspended.

Is there any way to either:

Prevent an windows app from entering the background while I perform my download
or continue peforming the task in the background (i.e. perform the task irrespective of whether the app is in the foreground or background)

Also, I don't want to use the BackgroundDownloadManager

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When the app is being suspended, all processes are stopped and and background task cancelled. Your last chance to do something is *Suspending* event - see more at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464925.aspx).

In your case, when you need to download big file in the background - the mentioned *BackgroundDownloader* would be the best option - it's designed for such tasks. In other cases you will have to convince user to leave the app in the foreground (a message?), also take care about lockscreen (see *DisplayRequest* class).

I'm not also sure but maybe you will be able to use *BackgroundTask* (separate process), triggered with *MaintanceTrigger* - but then user will be able to download the file only in specific circumstances and probably not right away.